# Pull items from sheet1 and use in sql query

Tags: vba, excel

I am using Excel 2016 VBA and I am trying to use sheet 1 were the manager puts their list of part number they want sales on. and my VBA SQL will pull the information from sheet 1 and put that part number in the query runs the query and displays the results on a new page and goes though the list of part numbers till there is nothing left on the list. Each part number could have 6 results.

I was using this code and it worked fine if everthing was on one page.

```
enter code here
ITEMNUMBERSLIST = RANGE("A2")

sql ="SELECT * FROM db WHERE iTEM IN(" & ITEMNUMBERSLIST & ") "

Set rstRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
rstRecordset.Open _
Source:=" " & sql & " ", _
  ActiveConnection:=cnnConnect
  Range("B1").Select
For Each rstRecordsetField In rstRecordset.Fields
ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Insert
ActiveCell.Value = rstRecordsetField.Name
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Next rstRecordsetField
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.CopyFromRecordset rstRecordset
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Do Until ActiveCell.Row = LR

ITEMNUMBERSLIST = RANGE("A2")

sql ="SELECT * FROM db WHERE item IN(" & ITEMNUMBERSLIST & ") "

Set rstRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

rstRecordset.Open _
Source:=" " & sql & " ", _
   ActiveConnection:=cnnConnect
   ActiveCell.CopyFromRecordset rstRecordset
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simply need to explicitly state which Sheet you're pulling the `RANGE("A2")` from:

```
ITEMNUMBERSLIST = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").RANGE("A2")
```

For the sake of read-ability, you may want to state the result sheet as well:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
```